# Yup validation schema for fields in multiple grid rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

In my React app, I have a JSON definition for grid rows as below

```
"gridItemsModel": [
    {
    "fields": [{
        "id": "nestedFld1",
        "mandatory": true,
        "value": "Nested Row 1 Column 1"
    }, {
        "id": "nestedFld2",
        "mandatory": true,
        "value": "Nested Row 1 Column 2"
    }]
    }, {
    "fields": [{
        "id": "nestedFld1",
        "mandatory": true,
        "value": "Nested Row 2 Column 1"
    }, {
        "id": "nestedFld2",
        "mandatory": true,
        "value": "Nested Row 2 Column 2"
    }]
}]
```

Now, I want to define Yup validation schema for this model. i.e. nestedFld1 would have same rules for both Row1 and Row2 and similarly nestedFld2 would have same rules for both Row1 and Row2.

Is it possible to define a Yup validation schema given that my id "nestedFld1" would be common for both row1 and row2 ?

For now, the validation I want is both "nestedFld1" and "nestedFld2" should be mandatory